# How to find the point in which a regression line will intersect the OY axis?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, linear-regression

I have a file in which I provide some data, the x and y values. My program draws the regression line of those points, but what I need now is to find the value on the OY axis, which my line will intersect if it will be elongated.

[What my program does now:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skzsr.png)

I need to simply make the line longer, intersect it with the OY axis, and find the exact coordinates of that point.

My code so far:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # To visualize

import pandas as pd  # To read data

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')  # load data set

X = data.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # values converts it into a numpy array

Y = data.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # -1 means that calculate the dimension of rows, but have 1 column

linear_regressor = LinearRegression()  # create object for the class

linear_regressor.fit(X, Y)  # perform linear regression

Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(X)  # make predictions

plt.scatter(X, Y)

plt.plot(X, Y_pred, color='red')

plt.show()
```

My code requires a file called "data.csv" which contains the coordinates of the given values. My example has the values:

```
5,0.8
10,0.7
15,0.66
20,0.493
25,0.5
30,0.21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you want something like this, where you can use the `intercept_` attribute of your LinearRegressor object to get the y-intercept at x equal to zero:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # To visualize
import pandas as pd  # To read data
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
txtfile = StringIO("""5,0.8
10,0.7
15,0.66
20,0.493
25,0.5
30,0.21""")
data = pd.read_csv(txtfile, header=None)  # load data set

X = data.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # values converts it into a numpy array

Y = data.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # -1 means that calculate the dimension of rows, but have 1 column

linear_regressor = LinearRegression()  # create object for the class

linear_regressor.fit(X, Y)  # perform linear regression

Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(X)  # make predictions

plt.scatter(X, Y)

plt.plot(X, Y_pred, color='red')

plt.plot([0, X[0]], [linear_regressor.intercept_, Y_pred[0]], c="green",  linestyle='--')

ax = plt.gcf().gca()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]